# Open all text files in given folder

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to open all text files in a folder and subfolder I give to program as parameter and search text in them. Now if I use . instead of path, it open files like I want to. But as soon as I give any other folder in my computer as parameter (not the one the object file is), it will not open files. How can I fix it? I have Windows, and I am using MinGw as compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "boost/program_options.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream> 
namespace po = boost::program_options;
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::filesystem;



int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Declare the supported options.
    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
    ("folder", po::value<std::string>(), "find files in this folder")
    ("text", po::value<std::string>(), "text that will be searched for");

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    filesystem::path current_dir (vm["folder"].as<string>());
    filesystem:: recursive_directory_iterator end_itr;//recursive lisatud

    for ( filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator itr( current_dir );
         itr != end_itr;
         ++itr )
    {
        //cout << itr->path ().filename () << endl;
        if(itr->path().filename().extension()==".txt"||itr->path().filename().extension()==".docx"||itr->path().filename().extension()==".doc"){
            ifstream inFile(itr->path().filename().string());
            //ifstream inFile("c:\\somefile.txt"); //this would open file

            cout<<itr->path().filename().string()<<endl; //this prints out all the file names without path, like  somefile2.txt for example
            while ( inFile )
            {
                std::string s;
                std::getline( inFile, s );
                if (inFile){
                    std::cout << s << "\n";
                    if(s.find(vm["text"].as<string>())!= string::npos){
                        cout<<"found it"<<endl;
                        }
                    }
            } 
        }
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "_it will not open files_" is not a very informative problem descruption, and "a folder" and "any other folder" are not very useful descriptions of your test data, either. Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: "it will not open files" - it will not go inside to loop while(inFile){} - a folder, and any other folder - a folder is a path I give to the program, it can be any path in my computer, and other folders are subfolders of that folder

Comment: You should check the value of `itr->path().filename()`. Because if the part to a file is `some/directory/foo.txt`, but `.filename()` is just returning `foo.txt`, you'll not be able to open it because the path is missing. Its an easy mistake to make with other filesystem libraries, certainly.

Comment: You are corrext .filename() is returning just foo.txt without path. And I believe it is the main problem I have, but how can I get the whole path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
ifstream inFile(itr->path().filename().string())
```

or more specifically, `itr->path().filename()` merely returns the *name* of the file, rather than the *complete path* to that file. If the file isn't in the program's current working directory, you'll have problems opening it: either no file by that name will be found, or a local file will be found with the same name, which won't be the file you actually wanted!

Whilst you're performing a recursive directory iteration, your current working directory won't change.

`itr->path()` returns instances of `boost::filesystem::path` when dereferenced... the docs for that class may be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path). I believe what you want to do is

```
ifstream inFile(itr->path().c_str());
```

This may not be the canonical or most efficient way, however.

Comment: native gets the whole path this far very good, but ifstream inFile(itr-> path().native()) gives me an error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char> :: basic_ifstream(const string_tyoe&). Adding .string() at the end of the row doesn't work either.

Comment: My bad. You may use `itr->path().c_str()` to get a plain old C-string version which should work for you. Answer updated.

Comment: I dont know if I am making some complete rookie mistakes, but it still doesn't work. The error is basicly the same no matching function, only the ending changed to (const value:type*)

Comment: Running out of ideas, I'm afraid. I don't have any machines handy with boost available on them. Maybe `itr->path().string()` or `itr->path().string().c_str()`? If that doesn't work, I can only suggest that you read through the docs yourself, as I can't really provide any more concrete help this weekend ;-) I note that both VS2013 and GCC 4.7 are both happy to construct an `ifstream` from a `std::string` path.